# How to get the linear index for a numpy array (sub2ind)

Tags: matlab, numpy

Matlab offers the function [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) which "returns the linear index equivalents to the row and column subscripts ... for a matrix... ."

I need this `sub2ind` function or something similar, but I did not find any similar Python or Numpy function. How can I get this functionality?

This is an example from the [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html#sub2ind_example1) (same page as above):

```
Example 1

This example converts the subscripts (2, 1, 2) for three-dimensional array A 
to a single linear index. Start by creating a 3-by-4-by-2 array A:

rng(0,'twister');   % Initialize random number generator.
A = rand(3, 4, 2)

A(:,:,1) =
    0.8147    0.9134    0.2785    0.9649
    0.9058    0.6324    0.5469    0.1576
    0.1270    0.0975    0.9575    0.9706
A(:,:,2) =
    0.9572    0.1419    0.7922    0.0357
    0.4854    0.4218    0.9595    0.8491
    0.8003    0.9157    0.6557    0.9340

Find the linear index corresponding to (2, 1, 2):

linearInd = sub2ind(size(A), 2, 1, 2)
linearInd =
    14
Make sure that these agree:

A(2, 1, 2)            A(14)
ans =                 and =
     0.4854               0.4854
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you want to use [`np.ravel_multi_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html). With the zero based indexing of numpy, and taking into account that matlab arrays are Fortran style, the equivalent to your matlab example is:

```
>>> np.ravel_multi_index((1, 0, 1), dims=(3, 4, 2), order='F')
13
```

Just so you understand what is going on, you could get the same result with the dot product of your indices and the strides of the array:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(3, 4, 2)
>>> np.dot((1, 0, 1), a.strides) / a.itemsize
9.0
>>> np.ravel_multi_index((1, 0, 1), dims=(3, 4, 2), order='C')
9
>>> a[1, 0, 1]
0.26735433071594039
>>> a.ravel()[9]
0.26735433071594039
```

Comment: This is a little misleading. This makes it look like you need to know the memory layout of an array to use flat indexing which is not true. The strides method will only work on C-Contiguous arrays, while this will always be true:  `A[idx] == A.flat[flat_idx] == A.ravel()[flat_idx]` if `flat_idx = np.ravel_multi_index(idx, A.shape)`. It's good to note though that `flat_idx` are computed differently in matlab and numpy.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved the problem for me, rewritten to be similar to the example given above.

The main idea is to create a helper array with the indexes using `arange` and `reshape`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.random.rand(3,4,2)

In [3]: A
Out[3]: 
array([[[ 0.79341698,  0.55131024],
        [ 0.29294586,  0.22209375],
        [ 0.11514749,  0.15150307],
        [ 0.71399288,  0.11229617]],

       [[ 0.74384776,  0.96777714],
        [ 0.1122338 ,  0.23915265],
        [ 0.28324322,  0.7536933 ],
        [ 0.29788946,  0.54770654]],

       [[ 0.13496253,  0.24959013],
        [ 0.36350264,  0.00438861],
        [ 0.77178808,  0.66411135],
        [ 0.26756112,  0.54042292]]])

In [4]: helper = np.arange(3*4*2)

In [5]: helper
Out[5]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])

In [6]: helper = helper.reshape([3,4,2])

In [7]: helper
Out[7]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11],
        [12, 13],
        [14, 15]],

       [[16, 17],
        [18, 19],
        [20, 21],
        [22, 23]]])

In [8]: linear_index = helper[1,0,1]

In [9]: linear_index
Out[9]: 9
```

Note that:

- rows and columns are switched in Numpy regarding to Matlab.
- Matlab starts indexes with 1, Python and Numpy with 0.