# Numpy: Assignment and Indexing as Matlab

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Sometimes is useful to assign arrays with one index only. In Matlab this is straightforward:

```
M = zeros(4);
M(1:5:end) = 1
M =

   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0
   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   1
```

Is there a way to do this in Numpy? First I thought to flatten the array, but that operation doesn't preserve the reference, as it makes a copy. I tried with ix_ but I couldn't manage to do it with a relatively simple syntax.

Comment: this was discussed before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257619/numpy-interconversion-between-multidimensional-and-linear-indexing   and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230179/how-to-get-the-linear-index-for-a-numpy-array-sub2ind

Comment: Hmm, they both don't seem to mention the `arr.flat` attribute.

Comment: I like this question better than the other two. It concisely brings the problem to the point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try [numpy.ndarray.flat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html#numpy.ndarray.flat), which represents an iterator that you can use for reading and writing into the array.

```
>>> M = zeros((4,4))
>>> M.flat[::5] = 1
>>> print(M)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Note that in numpy the slicing syntax is [start:stop_exclusive:step], as opposed to Matlab's (start:step:stop_inclusive).

Based on sebergs comment it might be important to point out that Matlab stores matrices in column major, while numpy arrays are row major by default.

```
>>> M = zeros((4,4))
>>> M.flat[:4] = 1
>>> print(M)
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

To get Matlab-like indexing on the flattened array you will need to flatten the transposed array:

```
>>> M = zeros((4,4))
>>> M.T.flat[:4] = 1
>>> print(M)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: numpy is C, not fortran order though, it is not quite the same.

Comment: Indeed. I have edited the answer to point out that difference.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using list indices:

```
M = np.zeros((4,4))
M[range(4), range(4)] = 1
print M
# [[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

In this case you could also use `np.identity(4)`

Comment: There is also a function made specifically for [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag_indices.html).

Comment: The example of a diagonal assignation, was just an example. I was asking how to use the more or less the same syntax that is used in matlab

Answer (score 1):

Another way using unravel_index

```
>>> M = zeros((4,4));
>>> M[unravel_index(arange(0,4*4,5),(4,4))]= 1
>>> M
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```