# Matlab sub2ind to python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

```
row = [1 2 3 1];
col = [2 2 2 3];
sz = [3 3];
ind = sub2ind(sz,row,col)

Result:

ind = 1×4

     4     5     6     7
```

I have the following example from the docs of Matlab. I want to produce the same with code with the same results in python. I have seen in other posts the case for 3-D array [How to get the linear index for a numpy array (sub2ind)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230179/how-to-get-the-linear-index-for-a-numpy-array-sub2ind)
But I want the case of a simple 2-D array, like I have shown. Code for answer is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def sub2ind(sz, row, col):
    n_rows = sz[0]
    return [n_rows * (c-1) + r for r, c in zip(row, col)]
```

Getting number of rows first. Then each index is that times (column - 1) + row.

using

```
>>> row = [1, 2, 3, 1];
>>> col = [2, 2, 2, 3];
>>> sz = [3, 3];
>>> sub2ind(sz, row, col)
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: But do note that Python uses 0-based indexing. This code takes 1-based indexing as input and produces 1-based linear indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.ravel_multi_index()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15230722/15786135) if you stick to zero based indices and take into account that Matlab arrays are Fortran style.

```
>>> row = [0, 1, 2, 0];
>>> col = [1, 1, 1, 2];
>>> sz = [3, 3];
>>> np.ravel_multi_index([row, col], sz, order='F')
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for finding the duplicate question. Next time, please flag the question as duplicate.